# Broadcast receiver does not receive intent in Redmi 1s on message receive

Tags: android

Broadcast receiver does not receive intent in Redmi 1s on message receive.It gives an exception:

07-24 14:14:41.030: W/BroadcastQueue(919): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x10 
(has extras) } to ProcessRecord{435b14a8 2897:com.miui.guardprovider/u0a10023} (pid=2897, uid=10023)
 requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.providers.telephony (uid 1001)
Please help me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: add the needed permission

Comment: `requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`

Comment: IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter(
    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
  getActivity().registerReceiver(readSMSReceiver, intentfilter);
  
  
  
  
  BroadcastReceiver readSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  }
 }
 
 and in manifest
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Answer (score 0):

As @skynet commented, you have an security issue with `Permission Denial`
Check on how to request `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` on the system you are using.

Most likely, in your AndroidManifest, you just have to`requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`

If are dinamically requesting for a register, then to as @Pavan commented